# Filtering rows in DataFrame with dependent conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies if this has already been asked:

I want to remove all rows with values between 15-25 in one column AND have a specific string in another column.

For example:

```
options = ['pizza', 'pasta'] 

df2 = df[(~df['columnA'].between(15, 25)) & df.loc[~df['columnB'].isin(options)]]
```

So if a row has a value of 15-25 in columnA but does not have 'pizza' or 'pasta' in columnB, then I want that row to be retained...

**Solution:**

```
df[~((df['columnA'].between(15, 25)) & (df['columnB'].isin(options)))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest to understand is negating the entire condition, like `~((...) & (...))`:

```
df[~((df['columnA'].between(15, 25)) & (df['columnB'].isin(options)))]
```

Or you can use [*De Morgan's laws* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), and specify this as `(~ ...) | (~ ...)`

```
df[(~df['columnA'].between(15, 25)) | (~df['columnB'].isin(options))]
```

So the negation of *x ∧ y* is *(¬x)∨(¬y)*.

Comment: Wow! This worked beautifully, thank you! Only issue is you have one too many brackets at the end ;)                                                                                                                                               df[~((df['columnA'].between(15, 25)) & (df['columnB'].isin(options)))]

Comment: @ConfusedDolphin: thanks, that should be fixed now :)